# Spring/JPA/persistence entity attribute field cannot be final?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, orm

I have a `Spring MVC` project using `JPA` which I have worked on for some time in the past without this issue. But now for some reason (likely an environmental issue as I have switch to a new laptop since I last worked on it) I am getting this weird error.

The project is essentially a tool for creating and performing surveys which are just a set of questions. There are multiple types of question such as "auto complete question", "multiple choice question", "integer question", etc which collect different types of data. Each of this question types is modeled by a subclass which extends an abstract class called `DdmQuestion` which looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ddm_question")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "question_type")

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"dataType"})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@question_type")
@JsonSubTypes(value = { @Type(DdmTextQuestion.class),@Type(DdmDateQuestion.class),@Type(DdmTimeQuestion.class),@Type(DdmNumberIntegerQuestion.class),@Type(DdmChoiceMultiQuestion.class),@Type(DdmAutoCompleteQuestion.class) })
public abstract class DdmQuestion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private int questionId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public int getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract String getDataType();
}
```

Note the `getDataType()` method.

Then, for each question type, I have a subclass extending this which looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ddm_question_date")
public class DdmDateQuestion extends DdmQuestion {

    final private String DATA_TYPE = "Long"; // this is the line with the error

    @Override
    public String getDataType() {
        return DATA_TYPE;
    }

}
```

Now, I've never encountered this error before (that I can recall) but `Eclipse` is throwing up an error here that says:

> "The Java field for attribute "DATA_TYPE" is final". That's all it
>   says.

If I remove the `@Entity` annotation from the class, this error disappears so evidently something in `JPA` doesn't like something about this but I never had this error before so I'm thinking something changed in a newer version. My POM is not particularly explicit with dependency versions so this would not be surprising.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and what the correct resolution is? I could just remove the "final" from the field declaration but this seems wrong to me as it is definitely a final value...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a constant value to me, why don't you add the static keyword also to it?

Comment: The JPA spec says clear enough that JPA cannot persist final/static fields

Comment: @galovics Hmm... Good question, I just tried that and the error disappeared! But I don't understand why...?

Comment: @NeilStockton but this code has always worked in the past?!

Comment: Define "worked". You changed *something*, by definition

Comment: It is an attribute of the class, thus the JPA provider tries to handle it. You can overrule it with the @Transient annotation.

Comment: @NeilStockton Well, yes, I suppose so but as I said in the question I believe it must be an environmental issue because this code came straight out of revision control from a stable build. Nothing in the code itself has changed but Maven may well have grabbed a newer version for one or more of the dependencies which may have caused this.

Comment: if you dont want to persist that field then annotate it as @Transient, normally .

Comment: which is why Maven recommends using fixed versions of deps. Some JPA provider (whichever you use) likely added a check for such things since they were sick of reading comments that "my final field wasnt persisted!"

Comment: Fair point, I will endeavour to be more explicit with version numbers but that still doesn't explain why it worked before. Let me clear, this field IS persisted. If I check the database on an existing deployment of the project I can see the "DATA_TYPE" field is there with the correct values despite the fact that it has always been declared as a "final" field... But you're saying JPA doesn't persist final fields so I am confused.

Comment: As for whether or not it *should* be persisted... well, probably not actually... it doesn't make much sense but nonetheless, it was.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a field that should not be persisted in the database you usually should take advantage of the transient annotation which would tell the persistence provider to ommit that field in its processing.:

```
@Transient
final private String DATA_TYPE = "Long";
```

If Eclipse is smart enough, it should stop highlighting the error altogether.

Answer (score 1):

in this linkshttp://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#Entities;

> An entity class must follow these requirements:
>
> - The class must be annotated with the javax.persistence.Entity annotation.
> - The class must have a public or protected, no-argument constructor. The class may have other constructors.
> - The class must not be declared final. No methods or persistent instance variables must be declared final.
> - If an entity instance be passed by value as a detached object, such as through a session bean’s remote business interface, the class must implement the Serializable interface.
> - Entities may extend both entity and non-entity classes, and non-entity classes may extend entity classes.
> - Persistent instance variables must be declared private, protected, or package-private, and can only be accessed directly by the entity class’s methods. Clients must access the entity’s state through accessor or business methods.